# I am trying to generate random matrix with based on some condition, How many matrices the can be generated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to generate random matrices based on the following conditions.
There will be 3X3 matrices. The first column can have 1 to 10, the second column can have 11 to 20 and the third column can have 21 to 30.
The numbers are not allowed to repeat in the matrix.
Example :

2 | 11 | 21
8 | 13 | 28
9 | 14 | 23

I wrote the logic to generate the matrix. Multiple matrices can have the same number but the distribution will be different for each matrix.

I want to find out the maximum number of matrices that can be generated based on the above condition?
Can anybody help me to do the math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing: each column pulls from a list of $10$ integers and takes $3.$ The first cell can be any of the $10$ numbers, then for any such choice the second can be any of the other $9,$ and for any choices of the first two numbers the third can be any of the remaining $8,$ yielding one unique ordered triple of the numbers. So, there are $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = 720$ such sets of choices.

Each matrix is the same as a trio of columns, so we can similarly consider first choosing any of the $720$ possible first columns, then any of the $720$ second columns, then the $720$ possible third columns, for $720^3 = 373,248,000$ possible matrices. Note that there is no overcounting here with two columns being the same and counted in different orders because each column pulls from a different set of numbers, so they can never be the same.